# Moq define strict mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Is it possible to define strict behavavior in Moq?

I want to call `ReadLine` twice, but define a different return value for the two different calls. See the code example below:

Moq example (fails)

```
[Test]
public void ExampleDifferentResultOnReadLine()
{
    var textReader = new Mock<TextReader>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    textReader.Setup(reader => reader.ReadLine()).Returns("Bla");
    textReader.Setup(reader => reader.ReadLine()).Returns("Bla1");

    var str = textReader.Object.ReadLine();
    var str1 = textReader.Object.ReadLine();

    Assert.AreEqual("Bla", str); // Fails: mocks returns Bla1
    Assert.AreEqual("Bla1", str1);
}
```

Rhino mocks example (succeeds)

```
public void ExampleDifferentResultOnReadLine()
{
    var textReader = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<TextReader>();
    // var textReader = new Mock<TextReader>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    textReader.Expect(reader => reader.ReadLine()).Return("Bla");
    textReader.Expect(reader => reader.ReadLine()).Return("Bla1");

    var str = textReader.ReadLine();
    var str1 = textReader.ReadLine();

    Assert.AreEqual("Bla", str);
    Assert.AreEqual("Bla1", str1);
}
```

Is the same possible with Moq?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mock constructor accepts `MockBehavior` enum value:

```
var textReader = new Mock<TextReader>(MockBehavior.Strict);
```

BTW Correct code to test sequence of calls will be (because RhinoMocks adds expectations and Moq just uses last value you provide):

```
var textReader = new Mock<TextReader>();
textReader.SetupSequence(r => r.ReadLine())
          .Returns("Bla")
          .Returns("Bla1");

var str = textReader.Object.ReadLine();
var str1 = textReader.Object.ReadLine();

Assert.AreEqual("Bla", str);
Assert.AreEqual("Bla1", str1);
```

Comment: Hi Sergey, thanks that is exactly what I am looking for. Could you be so kind to share a decent documentation link for Moq? All I can find is https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart. Is there a bit more detailed API / documentation out there that you know off?

Comment: @bas I just remember that :) But link you provided contains sample of customizing mock behavior. Btw strict mock just verifies that all calls to mock were set up. I think your second setup will override first value

Comment: LOL! I updated the question, and in the same time you updated your answer. Q & A are still in sync. You rock. Period. Thanks a lot!